# How to align floating point numbers in C# (left padding)

Tags: c#, floating-point, gtk#, number-formatting

I have the following floating point numbers, all with 2 decimal places:

```
2.47
57.83
93.92
119.20
```

I want to output these numbers as follows:

```
  2.47
 57.83
 93.92
119.20
```

How can I achieve that in C#, if the font is not monospaced?

**Edit:**

Or is there any invisible character that occupies the same amount of horizontal space as a digit?

Comment: Are you wanting to pad these as `decimals` or cast them to a `string` and then pad them?

Comment: If the font is not monospaced, you'd have to have some way of measuring the width of the space and the digits for the particular font you're using. Honestly, if this is not a console application, it would be far easier to rely on whatever features your UI framework of choice provides.

Comment: @Brian, I want to cast them to a `string` and then pad them.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, actually its a Gtk.Label

Comment: This may help: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is padding with [figure space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_space) (U+2007), its width is equal to the width of a digit:

```
label.Text = number.ToString("0.00").PadLeft(6,'\x2007');
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `string.Format("{0,6:F2}", number)`.

Since C# 6.0 from 2015, you can write `$"{number,6:F2}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not work, because it pads with spaces and a space character is using less horizontal space than a digit.

Comment: @sergej Can Java's `String.format` that you mention handle fonts with non-fixed width? Maybe I focused too much on the string and too little on the typography? A string, in .NET, does not hold information on the typographical characteristics, like the width of each glyph.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `Gtk#` before, but a quick Google search revealed [this](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp%3a_Labels).

```
label.Justify = Justification.Right;
```

This is a much simpler and more reliable strategy than trying to manipulate the string to the proper width.

Comment: @p.s.e.g, Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not work. I guess it's because I have a `MenuItem` `Label`.

Comment: @sergej This appears to be a perfect example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend that you update your question with details of what you're ultimately attempting to accomplish and where you're stuck. In any case, it looks like the `MenuItem` class has a [`RightJustified`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aGtk.MenuItem.RightJustified) property.

Comment: And BTW, yes, there is a [figure space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_space) which should be the same width as a digit, but I still wouldn't recommend this approach unless you've exhausted all other routes.